# how to display AngularJS ng-repeat is empty after ionicLoading

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, loading, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm using [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) for loading the news page, if no news found then this will run on my template: `<div ng-show="!news.length" class="empty"> Nothing to show ! </div>`

Problem: The empty div (Nothing to show !) is showing on the loading time, so if the news come then that div will hide. now I need to display that message after loading completed if no article found.

**My Controller:**

```
  .controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicHistory, $stateParams, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicFilterBar, $rootScope) {
    $scope.init = function () {
      var id = $stateParams.id;
      $ionicLoading.show({
          template: '<ion-spinner icon = "ripple" class="spinner-light"></ion-spinner>',
          duration: 20000
      });

      $http.get('http://localhost/json/article_details.php?id=' + id).then(function (output) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.news = output.data;
        console.log(angular.toJson(output.data));
      });
    };
  });
```

**My HTML Template:**

```
<ion-view ng-init="init()">
    <!-- If news not found -->
    <div ng-show="!news.length" class="empty"> Nothing to show ! </div>

    <!-- If news found -->
    <div ng-repeat="news in news">
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution. You can create a boolean variable on the scope that is set to true in the callback of your `$http` call. You add this as a condition to your *Nothing to show* message.

**Controller**

```
 .controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicHistory, $stateParams, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicFilterBar, $rootScope) {
$scope.isLoadingComplete = false;
$scope.init = function () {
  var id = $stateParams.id;
  $ionicLoading.show({
      template: '<ion-spinner icon = "ripple" class="spinner-light"></ion-spinner>',
      duration: 20000
  });

  $http.get('http://localhost/json/article_details.php?id=' +     id).then(function (output) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.isLoadingComplete = true;
    $scope.news = output.data;
    console.log(angular.toJson(output.data));
  });
};
});
```

**Template**

```
<ion-view ng-init="init()">
<!-- If news not found -->
<div ng-show="isLoadingComplete && !news.length" class="empty"> Nothing to show ! </div>

<!-- If news found -->
<div ng-repeat="news in news">
...
```

Comment: Solved the problem, Thanks :-)